# It seems to be a conflict between indicator-multiload and indicator-sound-gtk2

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, indicator-sound, xfce-panel

After upgrading from 12.04 to 13.10, indicator-multiload indicators in the xfce4 panel become invisible as soon as I activate indicator-sound-gtk2.
I don't know where i can find any error log for this, sorry.
Does anyone have the same issue ?

Best,
Tin

Answer (score 1):

indicator-sound is broken in XFCE, currently. 
To fix this, you can edit */usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service*

> sudo gedit /usr/share/dbus-1/services/indicator-sound.service

And change the content to this :

> [D-BUS Service]
>
> Name=com.canonical.indicator.sound
>
> #Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
>
> Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if [ -n "$(ps -U $USER | grep xfce4-panel)" ]; then
>   /usr/lib/indicator-sound-gtk2/indicator-sound-service;else
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service;fi'

This will load indicator-sound-gtk2 when using XFCE session, and use indicator-sound when another session (like Unity) is loaded.

---

I'm currently using Arch, but maybe this will help you :

[image: screenshot of xfce4 on Arch]

As you can see, it works for me. But interresting fact : it's not named indicator-multiload but **xfce4-systemload-plugin**. I think this plugin comes with xfce4-goodies package. 
That might be the indicator you'r looking for ?

Comment: Thanks, i already applied this workaround in order to make indicator-sound work, but having displayed both indicator-sound and indicator-multiload remains impossible ...

Comment: I edited my answer. Try to use "xfce4-systemload-plugin" instead. I don't know if that can help you.